# How to tell a configure script to use my own toolchain

Tags: makefile, build, autotools, configure, autoconf

I want to compile a [program](https://github.com/festvox/flite) for the xtensa lx106 architecture.

This architecture does not appear inside `config.guess` or `config.sub`. So doing `./configure --host xtensa` or similar produce an error.

How can I tell configure to use a toolchain (gcc, ld etc) that is installed on some arbitrary location on the filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `CC`, `LD` etc. variables on the `configure` command line usually does it:

```
./configure CC=x86_64-xtensa-linux-gnu-gcc LD=...
```

Or whatever tool you want to use.  See:

https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Compilers-and-Options.html